# Find a general solution for $y'' - y = e^{x} + x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am not sure how to tackle this problem when there is addition involved on the right hand side. I know that for $y'' - y = e^{x}$ yields $$y_g(x) = c_1e^{x} + c_2e^{-x} + Aex^{x}$$ and I can solve for $A$ with method of undetermined coefficients, but what do I do with the $x$ part?

How would this change if the equation was $y'' - y = xe^{x}$ (product instead of addition?)

Comment: You can solve apart $y''-y=x$ then try  $y_p=Ax$

Comment: I noticed that too, but why is this true? I think it has something to do with linearity, but I am not completely sure and can't find a reason in my textbook

Comment: Yes it's because it's linear;;;

Comment: You can also try $y_p=Axe^x+Bx$

Comment: Does $e^{x}$ act as a constant in this polynomial form $(a + bx)$?

Comment: $e^x$ is not a constant but a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'' - y = e^{x} + x$$
The polynomial characteristic is:
$$r^2-1=0 \implies r=\pm 1$$
The  solution to the homogeneous equation  is :
$$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$$
For the particular solution your guess should be:
$$y_p=Axe^x+Bx$$
Find constants $A,B$

Answer (score 0):

Solve $y_g''-y_g=0~~~(1)$,  $y_1''-y_1'=e^x~~~(2)$ and $y_2''-y_2'=x~~(3)$
The total solution is$$ y=y_g+y_1+y_2$$
For (1) take $y_g= e^{mx}$ we get $m=\pm 1$, so $y_g(x)=C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}~~~(5)$

For (2) Take $y_1=Axe^x$, then $y_1''-y_1-e^x=(2A-1)e^x \implies A=1/2 \implies y_1(x)=xe^x/2$

For (3), take $y_2=Bx^2+Cx+D$ then$y_2''-y_2\implies 2B-Bx^2-Cx-D-x=0 \implies B=0, C=-1, D=0$. So $y_2=-x$. The total solution is $$y(x)=C_1 e^x+C_2 e^{-x}+xe^x/2-x$$